# C# linq group to a list inside a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class

```
public class UserManagementClass
    {
        public string userID;
        List<AgencyInfo> UserAgencyList;
    }

    public class AgencyInfo
    {
        public string userAgency;
        public string userAgencyName;
    }
```

Now this list can have multiple instances with same userID, SQL is returning a list like this :

```
 userID        userAgency      userAgencyName
    1           5    Milk Commission
    2           5    Milk Commission
    2           2    Department Of CSV
```

Which I translate to this :

```
[{
    "userID": "1",
    "AgencyInfo": [
        {
            "userAgency": "5",
            "userAgencyName": "Milk Commission"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "userID": "2",
    "AgencyInfo": [
        {
            "userAgency": "5",
            "userAgencyName": "Milk Commission"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "userID": "2",
    "AgencyInfo": [
        {
            "userAgency": "2",
            "userAgencyName": "Department Of CSV"
        }
    ]
}]
```

How can I group it to look like this using Linq :

```
 [{
    "userID": "1",
    "AgencyInfo": [
        {
            "userAgency": "5",
            "userAgencyName": "Milk Commission"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "userID": "2",
    "AgencyInfo": [
        {
            "userAgency": "5",
            "userAgencyName": "Milk Commission"
        },
        {
            "userAgency": "2",
            "userAgencyName": "Department Of CSV"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried using multiple non-query expressions but no luck, Could someone please point me in the right direction?

My Linq:

```
var UsersList = Users.GroupBy(u => u.userID).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you share your LINQ?

Comment: `GroupBy(x => x.userID)`?

Comment: @SelimYıldız I just included it

Comment: @HereticMonkey That doesn't return "AgencyInfo" in one list per userID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` and then `Select` to define how you want the grouped results projected.

```
List<UserManagementClass> UsersList = Users
    .GroupBy(u => u.userID)
    .Select(_ => new UserManagementClass
    {
        userID = _.Key,
        UserAgencyList = _.SelectMany(u => u.UserAgencyList.Select(agency => agency)).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: how could I select multiple columns in this case: .Select(_ => new UserManagementClass
    {
        userID = _.Key, userName =...?

Comment: @AyoubSalhi - Are they unique to the user? If so include them in the `GroupBy` as `new {u.userId, u.userName}` and then select them from `_.Key.userId`

Answer (score 0):

This should be straightforward using Linq against your db (Linq To SQL, Linq To EF). I would expect in your db it is also represented as 2 tables which match to your JSON, however looks like you are retrieving that data from a single table?

Then you could achieve the same as:

```
var myUsers = Users.GroupBy(u => u.UserID)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        UserId = g.Key,
        AgencyInfo = g.Select(tb => new { tb.UserAgency, tb.UserAgencyName })
    });
```

Serializing this to JSON using Newtonsoft gives this:

```
[
{
 "UserId":1,
 "AgencyInfo":[
     {
       "UserAgency":5,
       "UserAgencyName":"Milk Commission"
     }
  ]
},
{
 "UserId":2,
 "AgencyInfo":[
   {
     "UserAgency":5,
     "UserAgencyName":"Milk Commission"
   },
   {
     "UserAgency":2,
     "UserAgencyName":"Department Of CSV"
   }
 ]
}]
```

Answer (score -1):

your line:

> var UsersList = Users.GroupBy(u => u.userID).ToList();

will work if you add:

> UsersList = Users.GroupBy(u => u.userID.ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();

as your userId is declared as a string, the groupBy groups strictly.

If your userId is going to be formed of numbers I'd change it to be int or similar. Otherwise if it needs to be string, you might be better off using a .Select after the GroupBy and creating a new UserManagementClass with the two properties, similar to the approach of Igor.